# Copying 85000 files...(takes literally for ever)

Tags: finder, file-transfer, nas

So I have these 85000 files (totally 2.5gb) that I wish to copy from my Mac to my ReadyNAS NV+ [X-RAID] with RAIDiator 4.1.10 [1.00a043]

It's a bunch of Matlab files.

Anyway, it's like it cannot be done. I went thru the wired network and let it copy all thru the night. From 9pm to 8am and it still said "30 hours to go..." Before that I managed to copy 30gb of data (30 files) in an hour.

Are there any better ways of copying these files that I don't know about? I'm using the finder.

Comment: Do you use a Virus scanner ?

Comment: What weird network? For normal human been wifi network with standard speed of 100-200 kbps you get 1 gig per hour, so it should take 2.5 hours!

Comment: no virus scanners.

Comment: Also, it's only slow when copying huge amounts of tiny files. One huge file 10 times as big is a lot quicker to copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your NAS supports FTP or SFTP, you could try with a client like Cyberduck. That could be more efficient than through the Finder (with AFP).

Comment: Didn't think about that :) Makes sense as I also can resume downloads/uploads if interrupted. I will try!

Comment: FTP did the trick!

Comment: also, another thing that worked was to SSH to my NAS and tar bzip the folders